# content search webpart ignore querystring filter when empty.

Tags: content-search-web-part

I'm using a standard content search web part. I have a querystring filter on the HRPortalRole managed property like this:

```
HRPortalRole:{QueryString.role}
```

When I provide a value in the querystring, everything is working fine but if I don't specify a value in the querystring it is not showing any content.

I basically want to ignore the filter when it is not there. So if my url doesn't contain the role parameter in the query string I just want to show all content no matter what role it has. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
{?HRPortalRole:{QueryString.role}}
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work on SP2016 On-Premises, unfortunatelly.